# horizontal accordion not working in Safari or Chrome

Tags: jquery, safari, accordion

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, as I'm relatively new to jQuery.I'm trying to build a horizontal accordion.  So far, it works fine in FF but not in Safari or Chrome.

In Safari and Chrome, the .content divs appear beneath their respective accordion panes rather than retaining their position and exhibiting the width animation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's a link to the example:  http://www.billjordandesign.com/jQuery_tests/horizontal_accordion.html

Here's my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.content').hide();
$('.content:first').show(); 


$('a').click(function(){

 $('.content').hide();
 $(this).siblings('.content').animate({'width':'toggle'}, 'slow', 'easeOutBack')
  });

});

</script>
```

...here's my HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">

<ul>

<li><a href="#"><span><div class="pane"><div class="verticaltext">Home</div></div></span></a><div class="content">1</div></li>


<li><a href="#"><span>
<div class="pane"><div class="verticaltext">About</div></div></span></a><div class="content">2</div></li>


<li><a href="#"><span>
<div class="pane"><div class="verticaltext">Overview</div></div></span></a><div class="content">3</div></li>


<li><a href="#"><span>
<div class="pane"><div class="verticaltext">Services</div></div></span></a><div class="content">4</div></li>


<li><a href="#"><span>
<div class="pane"><div class="verticaltext">Contact</div></div></span></a><div class="content">5</div></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

...here's my CSS:

```
#navigation{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 top:100px;
 width:1000px;
 height:400px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;
 color:#333;

}

#navigation a{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFF;

}

#navigation a:hover{
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFF;


}


#navigation ul{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:400px;
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style-image:none;
}

#navigation li{
 display:inline;
 border-right:thin #FFF solid;
 float:left;

}

.pane{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 height:400px;
 width:50px;
 background-color:#09F;
 float:left;
}

.verticaltext {
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 width:50px;
 bottom:50px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align:center;
 letter-spacing:-1px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.content{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 left:10px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#333;
 float:left;
 background-color:#FFF
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is great for sharing these kind of things, here's the code there: http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/D3Hm5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jquery looks solid, I made some html and css tweaks.  It's working for me in chrome

```
http://jsfiddle.net/generalhenry/D3Hm5/1/
```

Comment: Thanks so much, man. I often read this forum and find my answers that way...just couldn't get past this one.  This is a great resource and you rock. Seems to be working in Safari on the iPad. Will report back If there are any issues in the morning.

Comment: If anyone's interested, I took generalhenry's suggestions and added a little bit to make it more smooth.  The content divs now fade in when their respective panes are clicked.  You can see it in action here:  http://www.billjordandesign.com/jQuery_tests/horizontal_accordion.html. It is working in FF, Safari (& iPad), Chrome and Droid Incredible. And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/banjodrill/FqbCE/